# Good way to represent altitude on Openlayers?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

In openlayers I have data that is an array of [lat,lon,alt] points and I am able to draw a vector layer representing a path of this data using only lattitude and longitude. However, I would like to represent altitude data using color or line thickness. Is the a good way to do this?

Comment: It can be done with third party extension such as http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/style/map.style.gpxline.html

Comment: Perfect,  thank you!